# Hatched squares appear over Android MapVIew

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I am working on a new overlay for the map in my application. The overlay extends ItemizedOverlay and is used to place custom drawables on the map. These drawables are actually containers for a TextView, which is in turn drawn on the map.

That all works nicely, but there appears to be a problem in the way this is being cleaned up, because small squares ( approx 0.7cm x 0.7cm on a HTC Desire screen) have begun appearing (and seemingly breeding) spread across the map in an evenly spaced grid pattern (though often not complete screen cover), as seen in the image below:

[Null Squares](http://anony.ws/di-5SWW.png)

They are not 'holes' in the map tiles that have downloaded, rather the entire tile loads and then the squares appear over the top.

The most interesting part is that even after uninstalling the app, and then installing an old version which had never shown this issue, the squares still display. This is true of both the device and emulator.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Any hints as to what I've done wrong, or what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before when I use a different Google Maps API Key. Your API Key should be generated for your keystore, otherwise you can not see the map.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I don't think that is the issue I am having. I can see the map ok, it's that I also have the strange boxes loading over the top. The background in the image is satellite view of a desert, indicating the keys are working.